# Installing Xcode on OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, xcode, mac-appstore, install

I'm new to Mac OS X and I'm trying to install Xcode on OS X Yosemite.

First I tried using the AppStore, but when I click in "Install App" the App Store hangs (the little wheel in the top bar keeps spinning)

I tried installing using the command line by calling "gcc" to get the DevTools installation popup. Gcc and other utilities are installed, but not Xcode.

I searched the web and already rebooted the machine, cleared the Appstore cache but the installation doesn't start.

Has anyone had the same problem and/or knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have an developer account (I think an arbitrary Apple ID is sufficient) you can download Xcode in various varieties including other developer tools at [Downloads for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/).

Comment: It's worth noting that XCode 7 won't work on Yosimite, you'll need 6.4 .. thanks for the URL to the downloads.